# Why is ffmpeg processing time so slow?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert and compress videos. When I upload my video file it takes a long time to process. The video can be 1.2mb or even 5.8mb or even 10mb and its still slow, I am just there staring at the screen waiting for 20 minutes or even more. What can I do to speed up the process? If you need me to provide you with my code here it is

```
    $viddy=new Video;   
  $file = $request->file('file');   
 $fileName =uniqid().$file->getClientOriginalName();

 $request->file->move(public_path('/app'), $fileName);
            $name_file=uniqid().'video.mp4';
         $ffp=FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')
         ->open($fileName)
    ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
        $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480));
    })
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('s3')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'))

    ->save($name_file);

               $imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($name_file);


    $viddy->title=$imageName;
    $viddy->save();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How long *should* it take? How fast is your system?

Comment: @James thank you for responding, Do you see when you go on you tube to upload a video how fast the processing is? That is what I want. I shouldn't be staring at the screen for so long waiting for my video to upload. On top that the video file is not even big

Comment: YouTube doesn't process video files in the same request as the upload.

Comment: Yeah, YouTube most likely purely handles the upload on the initial request, then in the background processes it with a job queue. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Comment: @DerekPollard okay I understand now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing videos *is* slow, and the only reliable way to actually  speed it up is to throw more resources at it, which usually isn't worth it. YouTube is fast at least in part because they have Google's resources, which the likes of you and I usually don't.

However, you can speed up the user's perception of speed by moving the video processing to a message queue (which YouTube almost certainly uses too). That way the request will finish quickly, and you can process the queue in the background. Then, when it's finished you can notify the user in an appropriate fashion, whether that's an email or a notification via Websockets. As Derek Pollard mentioned, Laravel has its own queue implementation and you should refer to the documentation for that.

Another option might be to hand off video processing to a dedicated microservice, in which case that microservice would need to notify your application once processing is done. Or there are third party services that will do the same thing, if your budget allows for them. Regardless, this type of task is best done asynchronously rather than leaving the user waiting for 20 minutes or so.

Comment: Daily Okay I will try doing that. Thank you!